# Is MS Project 2007 compatible with Project server 2003?

Tags: microsoft-project

Can I use MS Project 2008 to access a project server 2003?

Comment: Do you mean Project *2007*? (There is no Project 2008.)

Comment: yes i mean 2007. sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that both products are not compatible.

> Project Professional 2003 is not compatible with Office Project Server 2007. Similarly, Microsoft Office Project Professional 2007 is not compatible with Project Server 2003.

Source: [technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197542.aspx)